# Water tank & pipe flow simulation software

Tags: windows, gratis, simulation, cad

I am looking for a tool that can help me simulate the water flow from two water tanks located at different levels. This is in relation with house construction and I would prefer to give priority to water from one tank to be emptied first followed by the other when both are connected to a common pipe.

Please refer me to a free software or an online solution that can simulate my requirement.

The requirement is simple and not really time bound. I am ok to spend time to learn the tool and implement the model for simulation. If it is a clean UI based tool, I believe it should not really take too long provided enough learning resources are available.

If more details are needed on the requirement, please refer [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405746/emptying-two-water-tanks-at-different-levels-with-priority-through-same-outlet-p) and [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/138829/two-water-tanks-at-different-levels-to-same-output).